# Adding a delay - getJSON and jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

```js
<script>

    //GET THE DATA
    $.getJSON('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/line/mode/tube,overground,dlr,tflrail/status', function(data) {

        var counter = 1;
        console.log(data);

        $.each(data, function(index,station) {

            $.each(station.lineStatuses, function(index,value2) {

                if (counter <= 16) {
                    if (station.name != 0) {
                        var stationName = station.name;
                        var stationStatus = value2.statusSeverityDescription;
                        var stationStatusReason = value2.reason;

                        $("#stationStatus").append(
                            $("<div>")
                            .addClass("row"));

                        $("#stationStatus").empty().append(
                            $("<div/>")
                            .addClass("stationName col-sm-6")
                            .append(stationName));

                        $("#stationStatus").append(
                            $("<div/>")
                            .addClass("stationStatus col-sm-6")
                            .append(stationStatus));

                        if (stationStatusReason != undefined) {
                            $("#stationStatus").append(
                                $("<div/>")
                                .addClass("stationStatusReason col-sm-12")
                                .append(stationStatusReason));
                        }
                    counter++;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have created some code to retrieve some data using getJSON.

Once I have the data I'm looping through and displaying the contents. My problem is I can display all of the content in one hit fine,  but I'd like to add a delay in between each loop so it displays a little bit like a news ticker.

I think I'm nearly there but my code in its current form is only showing the last item in the array. If I step through using devtools it seems to be doing the right thing but I don't know how to add a delay automatically?

I try using setTimeout and similar but it's ignored?

Comment: Can you reformat your code and include your setTimeout attempt? I posted a reformat here http://pastebin.com/Df3F2Y0C

Comment: As a quick answer to your question, setTimeOut sets the timeout for 'in the future' so if you were to set all the timeouts to the same value then they would all process around that same time. So if you want to stagger the updates, simply increase the setTimeOut*counter

Answer (score 1):

All the setTimeout are ran at nearly the same instance;
As in,

```
setTimeout(foo(),3000)
setTimeout(foo(),3000)
setTimeout(foo(),3000)
```

Will then run 3 foo()s all at once, 3 seconds later. 
In order to get them to run later simply change it to

```
setTimeout(foo(),3000*0)
setTimeout(foo(),3000*1)
setTimeout(foo(),3000*2)
```

Then you'll get your functions ran at 0,1,2 seconds.

In the form of your example,

```
$.getJSON('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/line/mode/tube,overground,dlr,tflrail/status', function(data) {
  function readLineStatus(station,lineStatus){
    if (counter <= 16) {
      if (station.name != 0) {
        console.log(station);
        console.log(lineStatus);
      }
      counter++;
      console.log('Counter: '+counter);
    }
  }
  function readStation(station,timeout){
    return function(){
      $.each(station.lineStatuses, function(index,lineStatus) {
        readLineStatus(station,lineStatus)
      });
    };
  }
  var counter=1;
  $.each(data, function(index,station) {
    console.log('station index:'+index);
    var timeout = 500*index;
    setTimeout(readStation(station,timeout), timeout);
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works great.

Comment: No problem, the question was pretty well defined and easy for me to test out your issue! (You'll most likely continue to get good answers on SO from questions like that) Since you're new-ish here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)